# SSRS Report Snapshot

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, reporting-services, ssas

My snapshot runs independently from DW load. Sometimes server gets busy with SSAS loads that causes an issue and snapshot doesn't capture the updated data version. So the question is it possible to call a snapshot anywhere other than Report Manager?  I really need a help with that. Thanks!

Comment: You can make walkaround and make internal parameter with datetime.now. SSRS will be think that date need to be snapshoted all the time.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am a newbie at report management. Could you please give a reference or example how can I achieve it?